# Fix for "Check Weather your Graph def interpreting binary is up to date with your Graph def generating binary "

Tags: python, tensorflow, react-native

I am running tensorflow with react native. I have a retrained Inception V3 graph. I used a GitHub repo example to test if a model other than my own would work, and it functioned perfectly well. When I attempt to use my own model, I get the Error: "Check whether your GraphDef interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef generating binary"

Dev Info{Python 3.5, react-Native 0.59, tensorflow 2.0.0a0, protobuf 3.7.1}From what I have seen, I have attempted training my model on an older version of tensorflow, (I was using 1.13.1, I tried 1.8.0). I heard that my version of tensorflow and protobuf may be too high to interpret my .pb file. This did not work though, and I received the exact same error.

Here is the recognition code:
async recognizeImage() {

```
try {
  const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
    model:require('./assets/retrained_graph.pb'),
    labels: require('./assets/retrained_labels.txt')
  })

  const results = await tfImageRecognition.recognize({
    image: this.image
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

On my docker container (where I running tensorflow serving) I have:

```
TensorFlow ModelServer: 2.1.0-rc1
TensorFlow Library: 2.1.0
```

The problem is related with your local tensorflow version that you use for export your protobuf model. I know that if you export your h5 model with tf versions 1.14.0, 2.1.0 and 2.2.0 you will have this problem at the time of perform inference. You can try to use tf versions >1.15.0 and less than 1.8.0. I think this happen because some tensorflow version doesn't support a particular layer at the time of export.

For change your local tensorflow version you can do

`pip install tensorflow==1.15.0`